# How do I fake a C function that takes a 2D array as input with Fake Function Framework (FFF)?

Tags: c, unit-testing

I'm having trouble figuring out how to correctly setup the macro in FFF for faking a function that takes an array of strings. Trying to pass the 2D array seems illegal so I created a typedef to try and get around that.

```
/*Macro for faking the function*/
#define getFilesInDir fake_getFilesInDir
FAKE_VOID_FUNC7(fake_getFilesInDir, char*, FileNames, uint16_t, char*, char*, 
int32_t*, uint8_t)

#define MAX_FILENAME_SIZE           400
typedef char FileNames[][MAX_FILENAME_SIZE];

/*Declaration in another header file*/
void getFilesInDir(char* dir, FileNames filesInDir, uint16_t maxNumFiles, char* includeString,
               char* excludeString, int32_t* fileCnt, uint8_t recursive);


/*Code under test*/
char fileNames[CFU_MAX_NUM_FILES][MAX_FILENAME_SIZE]; //Local variable
//...
getFilesInDir(path, fileNames, CFU_MAX_NUM_FILES, (char*)cfgExt, NULL, &fileCount, false);
```

This code gives me 2 errors. **arg1_history: missing subscript** and **struct fake_getFilesInDir_Fake has an illegal zero-sized array**

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The proper typedef for the 2D array is:

```
typedef char (*FileNames)[MAX_FILENAME_SIZE];
```

Comment: If you could, accept your answer when you get a chance, thanks!

Comment: I have to wait 2 days but will do!